# Why is this Promise skipping forEach loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having an issue with this code. I'm trying to return a Promise but for some reason when I debug it, it "skips" the forEach and rejects the function. What am I doing wrong?

```
removeOldBookings(rooms: Room[]) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const today = new Date();
    const roomsHolder = [];
    rooms.forEach(roomElement => {
      const bookingFiltered = roomElement[1].filterRoom.filter(finder => finder.provider.toUpperCase() === 'SELF');
      if (new Date(bookingFiltered.dateEnd) > today) {
        const obj = {...roomElement[1], hostBookings: [...bookingFiltered]};
        roomsHolder.push(obj);
      }
    });
    if (roomsHolder.length) {
      resolve(roomsHolder);
    } else {
      reject('error');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `filter()` returns an array. `new Date(array.nonExistentProperty)` would return invalid date so the `if()` would never be true

Comment: there shouldn't be a reason for a promise here since nothing is async.

Comment: @DanielA.White that's a good point!

Answer (score 0):

As charlietfl said, `filter` in `roomElement[1].filterRoom.filter(...)` returns an array, so `bookingFiltered` is an array. `bookingFiltered.dateEnd` is `undefined`, resulting in an invalid date, which is converted into `NaN` when used with `>` (greater than). `NaN` will never be greater than anything, so the code in the `if` block will never be executed and `roomsHolder` will always be empty.

If you want to get the first item of an array that matches a predicate, use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead:

```
const bookingFiltered = roomElement[1].filterRoom.find(finder => finder.provider.toUpperCase() === 'SELF')
```

---

Also, as Daniel A. White said, you shouldn't need to return a promise here. You can just return `roomsHolder` and throw `'error'`:

```
removeOldBookings(rooms: Room[]) {
  const today = new Date();
  const roomsHolder = [];
  rooms.forEach(roomElement => {
    const bookingFiltered = roomElement[1].filterRoom.find(finder => finder.provider.toUpperCase() === 'SELF');
    if (new Date(bookingFiltered.dateEnd) > today) {
      const obj = {...roomElement[1], hostBookings: [...bookingFiltered]};
      roomsHolder.push(obj);
    }
  });
  if (roomsHolder.length) {
    return roomsHolder;
  } else {
    throw 'error';
  }
}
```

If you must return a promise for some reason, you can also make the method [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or return `Promise.resolve(roomsHolder)` and `Promise.reject('error')` instead of wrapping everything in the promise constructor.